# Opening a dialog box

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog

I don't quite understand how this works. So I've made my dialog box.. or boxes. And I don't know how to make them appear in my code. Right now I'm trying to just get them to pop up right when I start my program so I can get a basic understanding of how this works.

```
 switch (message)
 {
 case WM_CREATE:
     HINSTANCE hInstance = ((LPCREATESTRUCT) lParam)->hInstance;
     CreateDialog(hInstance, "Whatever", hwnd, ABOUT_DIALOG);
```

That gives me an error in CreateDialog saying a parameter of type int is incompatible with DLGPROC. I'm assuming that I need to declare my dialog box somewhere?

And If I had a button on my very first start up window, how would I know that the user pressed the button? I'm going to once again assume and say that I need to catch it somewhere in the WM_COMMAND command?

Comment: MSDN exists for this purpose.

Comment: And believe me I looked, your comment is unhelpful

Comment: Well, the `WM_COMMAND` article has all the information related to handling control notifications, and the `CreateDialog` article has a handy link to the article for the procedure.

Comment: Detecting whether or not they click a button isn't my most major issue.. Its getting the dialog box to actually open.

Comment: I tried that yn and it didnt work. The answer below said you need to make it a type of DLGPROC which is moving things forward.

Comment: That's exactly what I was talking about when I said link to the article for the procedure. The compiler complains about the fourth argument. Looking on MSDN, you see it isn't an integer, but this `DLGPROC` with a link to more information.

Answer (score 3):

The final parameter, the thing that you pass `ABOUT_DIALOG` to, needs to be a [`DLGPROC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx). That is a function of this form:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(
  HWND hwndDlg,
  UINT uMsg,
  WPARAM wParam,
  LPARAM lParam
);
```

The compiler is telling you that `ABOUT_DIALOG` is not a function of that form. In fact the compiler tells you that `ABOUT_DIALOG` is an `int` which is definitely not the right thing!

To get it up and running with a default do-nothing dialog procedure implement it like this:

```
INT_PTR CALLBACK DialogProc(
  HWND hwndDlg,
  UINT uMsg,
  WPARAM wParam,
  LPARAM lParam
)
{
    return FALSE;
}
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx) says this:

> Typically, the dialog box procedure should return TRUE if it processed the message, and FALSE if it did not. If the dialog box procedure returns FALSE, the dialog manager performs the default dialog operation in response to the message.

So by returning `FALSE` we are asking for default processing.

Once you have the dialog up and running, you can then fill out the dialog procedure with any functionality that you need.

Comment: This works but the problem I'm having is now it says I cannot open my file for writing.. Its not open in the background or anything and I can't figure out why. Other projects open and run just fine.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about writing files.

Comment: @JesseMoreland, It's somehow having trouble with writing to your executable. If nothing else, you can log off and on.